# Weird break before English language citation

Tags: spacing, lyx, languages

I'm using LyX to write my thesis I've encountering this weird problem. When in-paragraph citations are formatted as English in my Danish document (which I do to get the spell checker working for English, this weird break is inserted:

[image]

As opposed to the citatioin not being formatted in English:

[image]

Curiously the bug doesn't happen if I change the language of the citation to German - only when it's English.

Any suggestions as to why this could be?

**EDIT:**

I've managed to produce this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[english,danish]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
 \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}[1]{}
 \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.\negthinspace}
}

\begin{document}
Kuhn udvider metaforen i sin karakteristik af udviklingen af paradigmer.
Om videnskabelige nyopdagelse hedder det: \foreignlanguage{english}{``Produced
inadvertedly by a game played under one set of rules, their assimilation
requires the elaboration of another set.''} Videnskabelige nyopdagelse, der i 
første omgang forsøges bortforklaret.
\end{document}
```

The problem is clearly this from the LyX thesis template:

```
\addto\extrasenglish{%
 \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}[1]{}
 \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.\negthinspace}
 \renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.\negthinspace}
}
```

What does that code do? What could go wrong in my working document if I delete it?

Comment: I can't [reproduce](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=7h5yefae) your problem with the code snippet provided. Could you create a complete [minimal working example?](http://goo.gl/5XLQU)

Comment: Did you add the relevant languages? Perhaps the hyphenation tables are broken/missing?

Comment: Strangely I can't reproduce it in a minimal document - but it's consistent in my working document.

Comment: If you can produce a [LyX minimal example](http://www.lyx.org/trac), please file a [LyX bug report](http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Six comment signs at the end of lines were missing, which produced superfluous whitespace.

```
\documentclass[english,danish]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{date}{}{\date{}}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ref}[1]{\mbox{\autoref{#1}}}}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
 \renewcommand*{\equationautorefname}[1]{}% <-- This was the first missing comment sign
 \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}%
 \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}%
 \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{sec.\negthinspace}%
 \renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Fig.\negthinspace}%
 \renewcommand{\tableautorefname}{Tab.\negthinspace}% <-- And this was the last one
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Kuhn udvider metaforen i sin karakteristik af udviklingen af paradigmer.
Om videnskabelige nyopdagelse hedder det: \foreignlanguage{english}{``Produced
inadvertedly by a game played under one set of rules, their assimilation
requires the elaboration of another set.''} Videnskabelige nyopdagelse, der i 
første omgang forsøges bortforklaret.
\end{document}
```

[image]